# Validate checkbox with JS

Tags: javascript, html, validation, checkbox

I'm searching a while for this and i can't found something that works for me.

This is my checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="main_account_form_checkbox" id="terms" name="terms" />
```

I need validate this checkbox, but do not know what I'm doing wrong. This is the steps in js file I'm working on:

Field: `var terms = $('#terms');`

On blur: `terms.blur(validateTerms);`

Checking:

```
form.submit(function(){
    if(validateTerms())
        return true
    else
        return false;
});
```

And the function:

```
function validateTerms(){
    if(terms.val().checked(false)){
        alert("Error!");
    }
}
```

Why I can't verify the checkbox? All other fields works except this. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't check the `.val()`, just use `is(":checked")`

```
if (terms.is(":checked")) //is checked
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **checked** property.

So to see if not checked

```
if(!terms.checked){
    alert("Error!");
}
```